# Typo produces unexpected results in PHP

Tags: php

Just found a piece of my code that had one original typo in it.

```
$msg = "Some text";
$msg .= " some more text";
$msg .+ " yet more text!";
$msg .= " last text";
```

Notice the `.+` that should be `.=`. What surprises me is that the code ran without producing any error, warning or notice and the output was:

`Some text some more text last text`

I was wondering why it did that. I know full well what `.=` and `+=` are but how is `.+` interpreted especially since there is no equal sign.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no `.+` operator, so that is `.` followed by `+`.

You're building an expression that consists of `$msg` concatenated with the result of applying unary `+` to `" yet more text!"` ([which is `0`](http://codepad.org/sMYKocvV) due to the cast to integer) ... and then discarding the whole thing because you're not doing anything with the result.

```
$msg .+ " yet more text!"; 
$msg . +" yet more text!"; // 1. PHP doesn't care about the spacing 
$msg . 0;                  // 2. Conversion to int from unary `+`
$msg . "0";                // 3. Coersion to string for concatenation
                           // 4. Nothing done with value
```

It's perfectly valid; it just doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: @lznogood: No problem! It's worthwhile here to consider what happens if you put the expression `"hello;"` as a solitary statement: nothing. That's really the crux of  this question.

Answer (score 2):

The `+` gets interpreted as a unary plus. PHP casts the string into an integer with the value 0 and concatenates it with `$msg`. However you do not assign `$msg` anything on that line, so `$msg` won't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

This works because the `.` is the concatenation operator, and `+` is the addition operator.

The line got interpreted like this:

```
$msg . (+" yet more text!");
```

The expression `+" yet more text!"` converts the string to an int (`0` in this case as when PHP converts a string to an int, it stops at the 1st non-number character).  It then concated the `0` to `$msg`, and ignored the result.